# Найти номер элемента массива с помощью jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Здравствуйте. У меня имеется скрипт для слайдера.
Мне нужно найти индекс того элемента, который содержит класс active с помощью jQuery. Как это можно сделать? В моём коде выдается ошибка *$slides[0].hasClass is not a function*

**HTML**

```
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide active">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $slides = $('.slider .slide');


    console.log($slides[0].hasClass('active'));
});
```

Comment: `console.log($slides.eq(0).hasClass('active'));`

Answer (score 1):

С помощью `index()`:

```
$slides.index('active')
```

Answer (score 1):

https://api.jquery.com/index/

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  var $slides = $('.slider .slide');
  console.log($slides.index($('.slider .slide.active')));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/1.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide active">
        <img src="img/2.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    <div class="slide">
        <img src="img/3.jpg" alt="">
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

в jquery есть метод [index](https://api.jquery.com/index/), достаточно выбрать нужный элемент и вызывать указанный метод:

```
$('.slider .slide.active').index();
```